# BUILDING REACT NATIVE PROJECT FAILS RCT-FOLLY

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build a react native project and i am getting the error below please how do i fix this. I am using a mac with intel chip.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KoyoApp-hfiovuiuzkvjwgbgmfhxrchwhyll/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/user/Documents/Koyo/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
i am using a mac with intel chip